# Amfphp Service Browser Not Displaying MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql, amfphp

I am developing my first project using Amfphp and am writing my first simple Service. Here is my getData method:

```
    public function getData() {
    // Connect to the database using PHP Data Objects (PDO).

    try {

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=amf_test', 'root', 'root');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Connection Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    // Set an Error Handling mode.
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Connected successfully\n";

    // Retrieve all rows.
    $tsql = 'SELECT * FROM authors_aut';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($tsql);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Echo the SQL Error Code
    echo "SQL Error code: " . $pdo->errorCode() . "\n";
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $row_count.' rows selected' . "\n";

    foreach ($pdo->query($tsql) AS $row) {
        $id_aut = $row['id_aut'];
        $fname_aut = $row['fname_aut'];
        printf("Data: %s (%s) <br />", $id_aut, $fname_aut);
    }

    // Close the database connection
    $stmt = null;
    $dbh = null;

    // Return the array.
    return $results;
}
```

When I go to the Amfphp Back Office Service Browser, select my getData method and call it I get my comments but no data. Before I added my echo and printf lines I didn't the Service Browser returned nothing leaving me thinking my Service was not working (it still may not be!). My comments appear to show that I have successfully selected the data from the MySQL database but is it being returned?

I welcome your thoughts.

Chris

Comment: a simple "return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);" should actually work. Have you tried returning some dummy data for testing? something like "return $row_count;"? Also, when you get this fixed, remember to get rid of all your "echo" calls as these shall corrupt your output.

Comment: I didn't know about removing out the Echos, thanks. I will simplify my code based upon your suggestion and see what I get.